# Laptop screen dimming after 15 seconds of inactivity after base update

Tags: power-management, brightness, cinnamon

Good Morning,

I, as of yesterday, installed the latest kubuntu base update, and it has caused my laptop screen to dim after 15 seconds of inactivity, which includes things like gotomeeting, zoom, watching videos, etc. I run the cinnamon desktop environment on kubuntu 22.10.

I've done some searching, and there (at least there used to be) should be an icon in the system settings called "Brightness and lock" which contains the control for this behavior. This icon does not exist in my systems settings. There is no option to control this within the cinnamon power management applet.

How can I maintain the previous behavior of not dimming while "inactive" while connected to ac power?

Thanks

edit: more information, after running this command:

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false

the dimming has changed to roughly a minute. It does that twice, then at the third minute it shuts off the screen completely. Obviously for video-conferencing this is unacceptable, especially when it worked fine before the update.

Comment: settings, power, power mode, 'power saver' does this .

Comment: @pierrely there is no option for power under settings - https://imgur.com/a/lraPo8S Power options also does not have any option for power saver

Comment: ahh, I am Ubuntu, gdm3 . different thing. maybe search for power settings for your Kubuntu.   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KubuntuPowersave

might be some hints there but an ugly choice by the looks of it.

Comment: @pierrely downgrading the packages to base 22.10 works without issue. sometimes an upgrade is actually a downgrade. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: and why I do a clonezilla partition backup before any such radical thing like an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

work around: downgrade these three packages to base:

xserver-xorg-core

xserver-xorg-legacy

xserver-common

why the updated version of these packages forces screen dimming after a short period with no apparent way to turn it off? who knows. Would love to know the decision making process of whoever thought it was a good idea.